# QMainWindow independent

Tags: qt, qmainwindow

I have two QMainWindows. I would like when a QMessageBox is displayed on a QMainWindow with an exec(), the other QMainWindow isn't blocked.

The two QMainWindow must be independent.

How do this ?

Comment: What does this have to do with `QThread`?

Comment: For the moment nothing. But I think QmainWindows must be independant as if they was QThreads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with QThread, the Qt documentation states that you can have only **ONE GUI** thread in a QT application.

What you should do is to set the modality flag to make the dialog modal, so it will be modal related to its parent window. Before executing the dialog, call:

```
pDialog->setWindowModality( Qt::WindowModal );
```

And don't forget to set a proper **parent** for your dialog object.

Qt documentation states: -

```
Modal Dialogs

A modal dialog is a dialog that blocks input to other visible windows in the 
same application. Dialogs that are used to request a file name from the user or 
that are used to set application preferences are usually modal. Dialogs can be 
application modal (the default) or window modal.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `show()` method to display each `QMainWindow` instead of `exec()`.

Comment: QMainWindows are displayed with show. And I need to use exec for QMessageBox to treat the result.